# Customizing the `No data found` validation message in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

The default message shown by `react-select` when there is no data found while typing is `No option`. Is it possible to customize this message?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [noOptionsMessage](https://react-select.com/props) `prop` like this:

```
<Select options={options} noOptionsMessage={() => 'FOOOO!'}/>
```

You can see it [working here](https://repl.it/@akrion/reactSelectNoData)